# Remove Div Wrapper or change Class name on some grouped elements in a nested map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, content-management-system

I have the following outputted html from a nested `.map` that is constructed from a for loop based on data coming in from a cms queried with graphQL.

[image]

1. I either need any div wrapping any NewBlock Sections removed, 
   or I need them to have a different class name than the BlockGridWrapper element’s wrapping div
2. I need the div that wraps any BlockGridWrapper group 
   to either be the  only group with a wrapping div
   or have a different className than the NewBlock’s wrapping div

Here is the for loop that is constructing the data array

```
const wrap = data => {
    const res = [[data[0]]];
    let curr = data[0];
    // let curr = 0;
    let idx = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].__typename === curr.__typename) {
        res[idx].push(data[i]);
      } else {
        curr = data[i];
        idx += 1;
        res[idx] = [curr];
      }
    }
    return res
  };

  const wrappedData = wrap(data.datoCmsProject.projectBlock);
```

Here is the output of console.log the wrappedData, so there is a typename that I am checking against and what I ideally want is the div wrapper to have a className dependent on that typename, but the nested loop happens after the div wrapper so I am stuck as to how to implement this

[image]

And then here is my nested `.map`. I Need the wrapping div to have a conditional class based on the typename ideally only for the `BlockGridWrapper`, however I can't have it individually wrap each element because I need it to wrap the entire block, but for `NewBlock` it doesn't matter if it has a wrapping `div` or if it has a different className either works. However I need to preserve the order of these elements because it is being populated from a cms.

```
{
      wrappedData.map(list => {
        return (    
          <div>   //I Need this div to have a conditional class based on the typename                  
            {list.map(l =>         
              l.__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent" ? (
                <NewBlock >text1</NewBlock>
              ) : (
                <BlockGridWrapper>
                  text2
                </BlockGridWrapper>
              )
            )           
            }
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove Div Wrapper or change Class name on some ...

Reverse the problem ... **don't render sth instead of remove sth**.

From that point we're facing common conditional rendering problem.

**In this case** (data structure) **we can simply check type of the first element before loop**:

```
{
  wrappedData.map(list => {
    let isNewBlock = list[0].__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent"
    return (    
      {isNewBlock ? (<div class="nb">) : (<div>)}
        {list.map(l =>         
          l.__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent" ? (
            <NewBlock >text1</NewBlock>
          ) : (
            <BlockGridWrapper>
              text2
            </BlockGridWrapper>
          )
        )           
        }
      </div>
    );
  })
}
```

or for 'removing div wrapper' (using fragments):

```
{
  wrappedData.map(list => {
    let isNewBlock = list[0].__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent"
    return (    
      {isNewBlock ? (<>) : (<div>)}
        {list.map(l =>         
          l.__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent" ? (
            <NewBlock >text1</NewBlock>
          ) : (
            <BlockGridWrapper>
              text2
            </BlockGridWrapper>
          )
        )           
        }
      {isNewBlock ? (</>) : (</div>)}
    );
  })
}
```

or even simpler/more readable, sth like:

```
{
  wrappedData.map(list => {
    let isNewBlock = list[0].__typename === "DatoCmsSingleProjectBlockContent"
    if (isNewBlock) return (    
      <>
        {list.map(l => (
            <NewBlock >{l.titleOfSection}</NewBlock>
          )
        )
        }
      </>
    );
    // the rest - notice different 'fieldset'
    return (    
      <div>
        {list.map(l => (
            <BlockGridWrapper>{l.titleOfGridSection}</BlockGridWrapper>
          )
        )
        }
      </div>
    );

  })
}
```

Comment: Let me try this, then I'll report back, thanks so much!